# How do i display labels and predictions - PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, cross-validation, databricks, azure-databricks

Create an algorithm to classify marketplace products, so I can not return the label of the prediction, I tried several commands but all of them have an error (below). How do I return label and percentage prediction(I'm using Cross-Validation)?

Example:

I want to inform you the product "7 Chakra Bracelet 7 chakra bracelet, in blue or black" and know which is label and accuracy (label return "Bracelet" for this product)

Training data

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([
("Bracelet"," 7 Shakra Bracelet 7 chakra bracelet, in blue or black."),
("Bracelet"," Anchor Bracelet Mens Black leather bracelet with gold or silver anchor for men."),
("Bracelet"," Bangle Bracelet Gold bangle bracelet with studded jewels."),
("Bracelet"," Boho Bangle Bracelet Gold boho bangle bracelet with multicolor tassels."),
("Earrings"," Boho Earrings Turquoise globe earrings on 14k gold hooks."),
("Necklace"," Choker with Bead Black choker necklace with 14k gold bead."),
("Necklace"," Choker with Triangle Black choker with silver triangle pendant."),
("Necklace"," Dainty Gold Necklace Dainty gold necklace with two pendants."),
("Necklace"," Dreamcatcher Pendant Necklace Turquoise beaded dream catcher necklace. Silver feathers adorn this beautiful dream catcher, which move and twinkle as you walk."),
("Earrings"," Galaxy Earrings One set of galaxy earrings, with sterling silver clasps."),
("Necklace"," Gold Bird Necklace 14k Gold delicate necklace, with bird between two chains."),
("Earrings"," Gold Elephant Earrings Small 14k gold elephant earrings, with opal ear detail."),
("Earrings"," Guardian Angel Earrings Sterling silver guardian angel earrings with diamond gemstones."),
("Bracelet"," Moon Charm Bracelet Moon 14k gold chain friendship bracelet."),
("Necklace"," Origami Crane Necklace Sterling silver origami crane necklace."),
("Necklace"," Pretty Gold Necklace 14k gold and turquoise necklace. Stunning beaded turquoise on gold and pendant filled double chain design."),
("Necklace"," Silver Threader Necklace Sterling silver chain thread through circle necklace."),
("Necklace"," Stylish Summer Necklace Double chained gold boho necklace with turquoise pendant.")

], ["id", "description"])
```

Token, Text processing and vector counter

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, StopWordsRemover, CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
# regular expression tokenizer
regexTokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol="description", outputCol="words", pattern="\\W")
# stop words
add_stopwords = ["http","https","amp","rt","t","c","the"] 
stopwordsRemover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered").setStopWords(add_stopwords)
# bag of words count
countVectors = CountVectorizer(inputCol="filtered", outputCol="features", vocabSize=10000, minDF=5)
```

Label Creation and DataSet creation

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol = "id", outputCol = "label")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[regexTokenizer, stopwordsRemover, countVectors, label_stringIdx])
# Fit the pipeline to training documents.
pipelineFit = pipeline.fit(data)
dataset = pipelineFit.transform(data)
```

So far the result of my dataset was this

[image]

Populating Cross Algorithm

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(predictionCol="prediction")

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=20, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0)
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator
# Create ParamGrid for Cross Validation
paramGrid = (ParamGridBuilder()
             .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]) # regularization parameter
             .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.1, 0.2]) # Elastic Net Parameter (Ridge = 0)
#            .addGrid(model.maxIter, [10, 20, 50]) #Number of iterations
#            .addGrid(idf.numFeatures, [10, 100, 1000]) # Number of features
             .build())
# Create 5-fold CrossValidator
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, \
                    estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, \
                    evaluator=evaluator, \
                    numFolds=5)
cvModel = cv.fit(dataset)
```

Creating the data to be classified

```
testData = spark.createDataFrame([
(10," 7 Shakra Bracelet 7 chakra bracelet, in blue or black."),
(11," Anchor Bracelet Mens Black leather bracelet with gold or silver anchor for men."),
(12," Bangle Bracelet Gold bangle bracelet with studded jewels."), 
(13," 7 Shakra Bracelet 7 chakra bracelet, in blue or black."),
(14," Anchor Bracelet Mens Black leather bracelet with gold or silver anchor for men."),
(15," Bangle Bracelet Gold bangle bracelet with studded jewels."), 
  (100," 7 Shakra Bracelet 7 chakra bracelet, in blue or black."),
(16," Anchor Bracelet Mens Black leather bracelet with gold or silver anchor for men."),
(17," Bangle Bracelet Gold bangle bracelet with studded jewels."), 
  (101," 7 Shakra Bracelet 7 chakra bracelet, in blue or black."),
(18," Anchor Bracelet Mens Black leather bracelet with gold or silver anchor for men."),
(19," Bangle Bracelet Gold bangle bracelet with studded jewels."), 
  (104," 7 Shakra Bracelet 7 chakra bracelet, in blue or black."),
(20," Anchor Bracelet Mens Black leather bracelet with gold or silver anchor for men."),
(21," Bangle Bracelet Gold bangle bracelet with studded jewels.")
], ["rowid", "description"])
```

I create a new dataset that should be sorted by removing only the labelIndex column

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[regexTokenizer, stopwordsRemover, countVectors])
# Fit the pipeline to training documents.
pipelineFit = pipeline.fit(testData)
datasetTest = pipelineFit.transform(testData)
```

Here I calculate new prediction with datasetTest

[image]

Up here everything worked out right

Now that problem comes, I can not see any information from the variable predictions

I tried command below, but all error occurs

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look further down into error trace you would find:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The columns of A don't match the number of elements of x. A: 6, x: 19

This means you have mismatch in number of features between training and test data (6 features in test and 19 in test).

Train data

```
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|      id|         description|               words|            filtered|            features|label|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|Bracelet| 7 Shakra Bracele...|[7, shakra, brace...|[7, shakra, brace...|       (6,[3],[2.0])|  1.0|
|Bracelet| Anchor Bracelet ...|[anchor, bracelet...|[anchor, bracelet...|(6,[0,2,3,4],[1.0...|  1.0|
```

Test data

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
| id|         description|               words|            filtered|            features|label|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
| 10| 7 Shakra Bracele...|[7, shakra, brace...|[7, shakra, brace...|(19,[0,1,2,3,10,1...|  8.0|
| 11| Anchor Bracelet ...|[anchor, bracelet...|[anchor, bracelet...|(19,[0,2,3,4,5,7,...|  4.0|
```

You are trying to encode your test and train data separately which is causing the mismatch in encoded data.

You would need to start with a combined dataset (trainData.union(testData)) where testData won't have labels. Then encode this dataset by transforming using pipeline. Then split the data back into train and test and then train your model and do predictions.

Comment: Manoj, I do not know if I understood correctly, but would not it be what I did in this part of the code "I create a new dataset that should be sorted by removing only the labelIndex column", where do I create a new dataset to sort by?

Comment: Try this simple change. Comment out the 2 lines where you recreate the pipelineFit object. `#pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[regexTokenizer, stopwordsRemover, countVectors]) 
#pipelineFit = pipeline.fit(testData)` and rerun your code. You have to use the same pipelineFit to transform your train and test data to get the same number of features.

Comment: Manoj, the code stopped displaying the error, the columns of the prediction are displayed (rowid, description, words, filtered, features, rawPrediction, probability, prediction), but the label column is not displayed. Do you have any idea how I can show the label?

Comment: label=prediction. I assume the whole purpose of the model is to predict the labels of test data. I would suggest going through a complete Tutorial and example test and train data preparation and model creation because there are a few things you are not doing correctly in your approach.

Comment: Manoj, thank you so much for your help. Because model always responded to the same label, it must be this same that commented. : -D. I will apply the stopwords, stemming etc processes and see if template responds correctly. Again thank you very much for the help